# Facebook story - custom layout

Tags: facebook, layout, facebook-opengraph

I can select a story type of object or map. But there I can only show texts. How can I create a custom layout like the following? With a table of data...

How do I create a custom layout for a story? Like following:

[image: http://www.robertjturner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Clipboard01.jpg]

Comment: I'm looking for the same. Did you find out how to do it?